Theism's secondary causation vs Simulation Theory

One persistent worry about the sole-source thesis has its roots in the
medieval debate over whether there is secondary causation (i.e.,
genuine causation by created things). Suppose that created things are
causes: fire really does cause water to boil, and ice really does
cause it to cool. If creatures can affect future events in this way,
why should they not at least help to bring about their own future
existence? Why should their causal powers be limited to affecting the
qualities of things without contributing to their own presence in the
world? Contrapositively, if created things cannot bring about their
own future existence, are they also unable to have any effect on the
future?
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/creation-conservation/

Simulation Theory can cleverly insert God (architect) into the philosophical understanding of our reality.
I would like to know what theists would argue against or for Simulation Theory.

Definitions

God is that singular uncaused, infinite, perfect being with agency, will, and personhood, through whom and for whom all things were made that have been made.

The Architect or An Architect is a computer end-user activating a simulation with certain parameters. The Architect and his hardware and software are caused, finite, and imperfect; he has agency, will, and personhood, but his computer hardware and program do not, at least when they are not running. Through this gestalt were made those things which have been made in that simulation; for the Architect were made those things which have been made in that simulation.


Syllogisms
1A: Definitions.
2A: That is not singular, uncaused, infinite, etc, which is gestalt, caused, finite, etc.
3A: Therefore God is not the/an Architect.

1B: Definitions.
2B: There is God.
3B: 3A
4B: God has revealed that God created this universe specifically.
5B: Therefore this universe was not made by the/an Architect in an act of secondary causation.

Since most theists are substance dualists, and currently popular Bostrom style simulationism is a kind of monism, one would be able to assemble a syllogism that runs: If persons, souls. If souls, substance dualism. Therefore not monism in any world with persons. But AFAIK one does not strictly need to be a substance dualist to be a theist, nor does one need to be a monist to be a simulationist in for example the style of Descartes' Demon. So I have left this one out.

Some references:
Descartes' Demon, one of the earliest framings of simulationism. Simulation hypothesis for the currently popular one.
Catholicism in re Monism and Pantheism, but useful as a generic Theism in re Monism and Pantheism.
God in Islam and Christianity for definitions of God and premise 4B.
